# Why can't I make my parameter like this?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)setPropertyValue:(const *void)inValue forID:(UInt32)propertyID {

}
```

The compiler doesn't like the const *void, for some reason. When I have that, it says:

```
error: expected ')' before 'void'
```

When I make the parameter like (UInt32)foo there is no problem. Does const *void only work in functions?

I need a parameter which can be a "pointer to anything" like UInt32, Float64, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
(const void*)
```

instead. `(const * void)` doesn't work in C++ / C either.

Comment: my fault. I see... const isn't the datatype. void is it (sort of).

Comment: `void *` is the datatype - a pointer to data of unspecified type. `const` is a qualifier that means the thing being pointed to must not be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean `const void *`?